# Validate SVG with custom namespace against DTD

Tags: xml, svg, dtd

I generate SVGs like the following

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:foobar="http://foobar.com">
<path d="..." foobar:foo="bar"/>
</svg>
```

Without the custom attribute `foo`(and the namespace `foobar`), the entire SVG validates against the DTD. Clearly, I'm using the custom namespace wrong, as adding the `foobar` namespace and associated attributes causes `xmllint`to fail validation, starting with the declaration of `xmlns:foobar=...`, which itself *is not an element of `svg`*. Is my declaration wrong? Is it even possible to validate against the DTD when using custom namespaces/attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're validating against the SVG 1.1 2nd ed. DTD at its official URL shown below, you could make use of the extensive customization features of the SVG DTD by re-defining ("preempting") the default empty string value for the `SVG.External.attrib` parameter entity such that it contains attribute list declaration fragments for your custom attributes (plus the `xmlns:foobar` declaration):

```
<!DOCTYPE svg
  SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
  <!ENTITY % SVG.External.attrib
    "xmlns:foobar CDATA #IMPLIED
     foobar:foo CDATA #IMPLIED">
]>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:foobar="http://foobar.com">
  <path d="M 0 0 z" foobar:foo="bar"/>
</svg>
```

The SVG DTD ultimately expands the replacement text for `SVG.External.attrib` in individual declarations for SVG elements. There might be more appropriate parameter entities to customize/overwrite depending on your purpose, such as `SVG.Core.extra.attrib`.

Note the document, when run through `xmllint --valid --loaddtd`, produces unrelated warnings on my Ubuntu machine where an SVG DTD is cached locally, as evidenced by `xmllint`'s quick response compared to fetching the DTD via http (which results in other warnings for me).